# Not able to execute Ant build tool on Jenkins agent

Tags: jenkins, ant, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-agent

I want to execute Ant on Jenkins agent machine using Jenkinsfile. I tried configuring the Ant tool on agent machine but no success. Please see attached file and code for the reference.

[image]

```
pipeline {  

agent any

environment {
    ANT_HOME = tool('MyAnt')
}
stages {
    stage("Build") {
        agent {label 'redhat_slave1'}
        steps {
            echo "Building application..."   
            sh '$ANT_HOME/bin/ant clean'
        }
    }
    stage("Unit Tests") {
        agent { 
            label 'redhat_slave1'
        }
        steps {
            echo "Unit tests (JUnit)..."
            echo "Mutation tests (pitest)..."

            
        }
    }
    stage("Functional Test") {
        agent { 
            label 'redhat_slave2'
        }
        steps {
            echo "Selenium tests..."
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that this ant tool exists on this slave and is accessible by the user that's used by jenkins?

Comment: @hakamairi As you see I mentioned in my question that I configured Ant path on slave machine using jenkins master. There is no separate Ant tool configured on slaves